# Gridview click on header for sorting triggering row command

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I have a fairly simple GridView. This is the markup for Columns:

```
 <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="JD Name" SortExpression="FullName"
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="180px" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton CommandName="edt" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("JurisdictionID") %>' runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FullName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="JD Abbreviation" ItemStyle-Width="200px"  DataField="JDAbbreviation" SortExpression="JDAbbreviation"
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

                 <asp:TemplateField 
                    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkStat" CommandName="inac" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("JurisdictionID") %>' 
                        runat="server" Text='<%#Utils.GetStatusString((bool) Eval("IsActive")) %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
```

However, when I click on of the columns for sorting, it first triggers a row command event and then comes to sorting event. Can anybody tell me what is the mistake I am doing? In the RowCommand argument I get the SortExpression. This is really funny for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sort` is a `row command`.  Check out this MSDN [GridView.RowCommand Event article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) for more details.

In your row command event you should add an `if` statement so you can determine when the row command code should execute.  Use e.CommandName.

```
void ContactsGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
  // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
  if(e.CommandName=="Add")
  {
    // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
    // property to an Integer.
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
    // by the user from the Rows collection.
    GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];

    // Create a new ListItem object for the contact in the row.     
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    item.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text) + " " +
    Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[3].Text);

    // If the contact is not already in the ListBox, add the ListItem 
    // object to the Items collection of the ListBox control. 
    if (!ContactsListBox.Items.Contains(item))
    {
      ContactsListBox.Items.Add(item);
    }
  }
}
```